# How can I make RecyclerView slide in and out of the screen?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout

I need to achieve the following behavior:
[image: Imgur]

I have an activity with some data and views in it. At the bottom there is a search bar. What I need is to make `RecyclerView` slide into the screen or just pull it up when you start typing in the search bar. When `RecyclerView` is on the screen and user keeps scrolling down I need to collapse it back to the starting position.

What would be the right approach to achieve this behavior?

Comment: Looking for anim similar to one showed here https://proandroiddev.com/enter-animation-using-recyclerview-and-layoutanimation-part-1-list-75a874a5d213?

Comment: @Raghunandan not exactly. In your example RecyclerView is already on the screen and being populated with views. In my case, I have a View with different data and recyclerView is initially collapsed at the bottom of the screen. The recyclerView can be expanded with swipe up and collapsed with swipe down gestures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [BottomSheetDialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetDialog) as an option and put there your recycler as a part of its layout. 
Here is the design [guidelines](https://material.io/design/components/sheets-bottom.html#modal-bottom-sheet) and here is the [implementation](https://gist.github.com/marc0x71/061f53453152d0a68c20).

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using BottomSheet hosting the fragment with RecyclerView in it.